Core Bluetooth cancelPeripheralConnection not disconnecting peripheral in iOS 17
In iOS 17, I'm encountering an issue where cancelPeripheralConnection from Core Bluetooth does not disconnect the peripheral device, and no error is returned. This is specifically occurring on iOS 17, I have tested on iPhone 15 [iOS 17.5.1] and iPhone XR [iOS 17.5.1]
I am using CoreBluetooth's CBCentralManager cancelPeripheralConnection method to disconnect a peripheral that was connected by the same CBCentralManager.
Ideally, cancelPeripheralConnection should disconnect the peripheral, but in my case, it seems CoreBluetooth is not responding to this request.
I am not receiving any errors in the didDisconnectPeripheral delegate method callback, which indicate successful disconnection, but we can still see that peripheral is connected when we go to Control Centre. It stays connected even after closing the app.
This issue is not reproducible on another testing device - iPhone XR also running iOS 17.5.1.
Could you please advise on how to troubleshoot or if there are known issues related to this behaviour in iOS 17?
Thank you!

As the documentation states, other applications may still be connected to the peripheral, so closing a local connection doesn't guarantee that the underlying physical connection will be closed immediately.
From what you describe in your question, this perfectly seems to be the expected behaviour.
Have you ensured that no other application on the device is maintaining the connection?

Thanks for your input.
Yes, I understand that we can only request a disconnection and cannot guarantee that the peripheral will be disconnected.
However, my app works fine on all other iOS versions and device models. Typically, when we request the Central Manager to disconnect, it does so within a few seconds, and we can confirm the disconnection from the Control Center.
The issue arises only with iOS 17.5.1 or on the iPhone 15. I can assure you that no other app is using this Bluetooth connection.

But that sounds like a message that should be sent to Apple Developer support

Yes , I have posted a question on Apple Developer Forum as well.
FYI: After restarting my iPhone , I was not able to reproduce this issue anymore. Seems like universal solution worked in this case as well.
